# Run tests at build time for specific build types on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a bunch of junit tests. I also have different build types - debug, staging and release. I am aware that I can go to `Run/Debug Configurations` on Android Studio, select my application configuration, and at the bottom of the right panel, under `Before launch`, I can add a new configuration to run my tests. This is great, but it runs all my unit tests no matter which build type I have selected, which pains me greatly.

I want to be able to build with both `debug` and `release` without the tests being executed. On the other hand, I want the tests to be executed when I choose the `staging` build type and build the project.

Is there a way to force the tests to **run only on a specific build type**?